# Find In Folder not showing all expected results Sublime Text 2

Tags: php, sublimetext2

I've got a project containing over 30,000 files.  When I want to find something within those files, I right-click the project and use Find in Folder (or press CTRL+SHIFT+F), enter my search term and make sure the 'WHERE' is my project then click Find.  This opens up the Find Results tab and shows me every file where that search term exists.  This normally works fine but there's one search it won't show all results for.

I've got 4 PHP files that all have the variable of $findthis.  When I try and search for that variable, it only brings back 3 out of the 4 files and I'm not sure why.  It's spelt correctly in each file and when I open the 4th file and do a find within it, it can find it perfectly, just not when using the Find In Folder option.  I've even gone into the file, copied the variable name and pasted that value into Find In Folder and it still only shows me 3 files and not 4!

The only settings I've changed in the preferences 'Settings - User' file are the following:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Cobalt.tmTheme",
    "detect_slow_plugins": false,
    "font_size": 9,
    "file_exclude_patterns": ["/*.jpg","/*.jpeg","/*.gif","/*.png","/*.tif*","/*.bak*","/*.sql","/*.tar*","/*.ttf","/*.jar","/*.swf"],
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "word-wrap": false
}
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have any exclusions in your project settings as well. Can you provide context where `$findthis` is not found?

Comment: I can see the filepath to where it's going to search in the Where field, is there anywhere else that I would have exclusions?  I can't see any difference between the files, they are all PHP files and the name of the variable (and it's string value) are exactly the same, the only difference is the rest of the content within the files.  Maybe something is wrong with the file and not with Sublime Text...

Comment: What are the files' full path? Also Sublime Text 2 has some default exclude file, folder and binary patterns in Default/Preferences.sublime-settings. Make sure none of them matches.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the search options in the dialog:

- you may have set the "Regular expression" option in search (the left button in the search dialog, with ".*"). So the $ sign is interpreted as an end of line.
- or you have the "whole word option" which is set (the button with double quotes);

**Update** 
I made some tests and the results are rather surprising when looking for a string starting with a $ symbol if any of these options are activated. Even for a basic search in the current tab.

`$test` is not found whatever is its context if the "whole word" option is activated.